# HttpServletRequest object's fields are truncated on delay. Why?

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a Spring application in one of whose controllers I receive `HttpServletRequest`'s object. I have to then log some of the header information of this object into a database, for which I start a thread. Then I pass this `HttpServletRequest` object into the thread and try to access fields by methods such as `request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT)`. This runs fine, but when I debug and place a breakpoint before this access, I get null values in all these headers. Also whenever the thread is run late, the header values are turned into null. One possible explanation is that after a certain time elapses, the container frees up memory. But why and how? Is there a time limit to this?

Answer (score 3):

The instances of the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` classes must not be used outside of the servlet service method. Servlet containers can (and do) reuse the same request/response objects when calling servlet methods by changing the internal state of these objects to correspond the current http request.

If you have a background task that generates the response then you need to look into [async servlet processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets012.htm).

If you have a background task that just needs some data from the request but the response is generated immediately then you need to copy all the information you need from the request into some other object and pass that object into your background task.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why should not they be reused outside the servlet service method? There was no other call to the server at the time. Then why did the container allegedly truncate the request object's headers? Currently to avoid getting null values in the request headers I am doing what you suggested, ie passing them explicitly into my thread.